# Добавляет ненужный элемент в отображение TreeMap

Tags: java, строки, map, substring

Код:

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
try{
       output.write("Input first and last name of students(q for exit): \n");
       output.flush();
       String str; int b = 0;
       do{
            str = input.readLine();
            if (str!="q") mStudents.put(str, b);
       } while (str!="q");
       input.close();
} catch (IOException e){
}
```

В отображение вводится элемент "q", из-за чего в функции-сравнении объектов возникает исключение:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
```

Если добавить в цикл do{}while() вывод введенного значения, то "q" там присутствует. В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Строки в Java это ссылочный тип. Сравнение `==` разных строковых переменных всегда дает отрицательный результат. Надо:

```
!str.equals("q")
```